# Solspace Calendar: Color Code events by Category

Tags: solspace-calendar

I would like to color code the day cell according to the event category. I have 4 categories Islamic, TRA, Global and UAE.Following is a screenshot of the calendar I would like to have. [image]

Can anyone help me with an example code that does this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include your template code as it currently stands.

Answer (score 6):

On the {exp:calendar:cal} tag, I believe you could do 
enable="categories". You could then output the category for each event with class="category{categories}{category_id}{/categories}" and then just create some CSS to apply the colour for each class - such as category1, category2 etc.

Something like that might work.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented it and it is working. However, I would like to change the day format from Sunday, Monday to Sun, Mon..

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar but categories were being used for something else, so in the calendar setup I split event categories into separate calendars and then used the events calendar ID to create class names as explained above. Same solution, different route.